# Unable to connect to Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle 11XE a while back - suddenly I am getting ORA-01034 and ORA-27101 errors when trying to connect

My ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID appear to be correct.

My listener.ora file is:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    ))

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Home-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
   (PROGRAM = extproc)
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

The following Windows Services are all started:

```
OracleJobSchedulerXE 
OracleMTSRecoveryService 
OracleServiceXE       
OracleXEClrAgent 
OracleTNSListener
```

When I switch Windows Firewall off (just in case it is blocking port 1521), it still brings up the error

What else can I check?

Comment: Can you confirm that the ORACLE.exe is running (e.g. through task manager or through powershell Get-Process ORACLE)?

Comment: @Patrick - ORACLE.EXE is NOT present in the list of processes on Task Manager. When I attemopt to start my XE stufF (through http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 ) I get "Problem loading page". Is this connected and if so, help!!!!!

Comment: I have some experience with 10gXE, not so much with 11g.  Typically, the ORA-01034 is thrown when the database is down. Burleson has cited that it can be a memory problem (e.g. SGA requires more space that is available, http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01034_oracle_not_available.htm).

Comment: Yes, without oracle.exe in your task manager, that tells us that Oracle is not up and running (yet you have 5 services running).

Comment: How would I increase the SGA space? And get Oracle running?

Answer (score 0):

It must have been a permissions issue for some reason

When I ran the Start Database batch file, it just hung

From the SQL Command Line, I typed

```
STARTUP
```

and got

```
ORA-01038: insufficient privileges
```

So I connected using

```
connect sys as sysdba
```

and got

```
Connected to an idle instance
```

I then used

```
STARTUP
```

again and it started! I had not changed anything else. I can only assume I will have to change my Start.bat file to connect as sysdba first

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem when one of my drives used by Oracle had 25GB used and only 5GB free space.  I increased the size to 60GB and it fixed the problem.